# Unable to access methods in another winform

Tags: c#, winforms, reference

I have two projects in my solution called ePad demo and PLHardwareHelper. I have added a reference to the PLHardwareHelper for the epad demo and I can successfully access methods in epad from hardwarehelper.

The problem is though that I cannot access anything in hardware helper from epad. I can't added a reference because it says it will result in a circular reference. I can't even add the namespace as a reference in the form.

How can access methods in hardwarehelper from within epad without adding a reference?

I have added a third reference called ApplicationJoin so I can add it's reference to both the other projects but it still complains that it can't find it. I have added an image below to demonstrate:

[image: solution]

The code from ApplicationJoin:

```
namespace ApplicationJoin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static string _imagevalues = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void ImageValues(string value)
    {
        _imagevalues = value;
    }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The issue:

[image: theissue]

The error on the blue squiggly line is:

> The name 'ApplicationJoin' does not exist in the current context

I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the solution but it still doesn't work.

Comment: this is a common mistake that people make can you perhaps show the class structure or heading or some small snippet that relates to your code.. it's very easy for one to get caught up in this `circle jerk` so to speak.. also too creating a 3rd project and referencing it that was is also another viable option

Comment: This error means that you reference ePad within PLHardwareHelper and PLHardwareHelper within ePad. Everything clear for me...

Comment: @GrantWinney The problem is that when I added the reference for this to the two projects, it come up with a yellow !triangle and said it couldnt be found.

Comment: @GrantWinney that is current, also just now I manually browsed to the DLL. The exclamation mark removed itself from the reference but i still can't access it from inside the forms.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have added screenshots. It's a shame you closed the question off so quickly before my response because now it prevents others from providing a potential answer.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access it as if it were static, instead of having an instance of `Form1`.  The _method_ is static, but not the _class_ `Form1`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott According to the code `ImageValues` is a static method of `Form1`

Comment: @GrantWinney the blue line is The name 'ApplicationJoin' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @DonBoitnott I can't even access the reference at the moment.

Comment: @GrantWinney All of them set to .net 4 but still causing a problem.

Comment: Are you running these from an odd location?  Copying the files in a build step or something, where the EXE and referenced assembly are in different places?  Make sure the referenced assembly is "copy local".

Comment: I suspect that you are not using the correct (full) namespace. Check the ApplicationJoin assembly. Look at the property of the ApplicationJoin project to confirm.